# file.Exists() returns false although I can reach these remote files from file explorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, webforms

Because I have authorization, I can reach files that in another server via file explorer like this:

[image]

When I want to download items from that folder in a web project, I get "false" from file.Exists() method. My code is below. What is wrong?

```
fileNameToShow = fileNameToShow.Replace(" ", "_");
var fileNameAndPath = "\\\\supplier\\SupplierFiles\\Live\\20\\290B_T.N.E.JPG";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileNameAndPath);
file.Refresh();
if (file.Exists)
{
 // Send the file to the browser
     Response.Clear();
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename= " + fileNameToShow + "; size=" + file.Length.ToString());
     Response.TransmitFile(fileNameAndPath);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
 }
 else
 {
     throw new Exception("File does not exist!");
 }
```

Comment: If you run this code in iis, it could still be authorization as iis does not run as your user but default it runs as "local system".

Comment: From memory, `Directory.Exists` and `File.Exists` don't work with a network path. The solution is to do `Directory.GetFiles` and check manually the result... Try `Directory.GetFiles("\\\\supplier\\SupplierFiles\\Live\\20")` to check this assumption.

Comment: Web projects, those that run under the IIS, run under an application pool that is executed under some credentials. Probably the network shared has not permissions to that user although you have them

Comment: Check [configuring application pool identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: What does your web config look like?

Comment: @vernou `From memory, Directory.Exists and File.Exists don't work with a network path`, they sure do. IMHO the user doesn't have the permissions as @Connor and @Cleptus has mentioned.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Learn the differences and the cause is clear.

Comment: Permissions issue. Make sure the account running the site has permissions.